# MS Access Convert like function to Memo Data Type

Tags: sql, ms-access, formatting, ms-access-2007, rtf

I need to use rich text formatting for a field in a report in MS Access in order to use character spacing. In the report, attempting to change the Text Format in the field's properties from Plain Text to Rich Text Produces the error: "The setting you entered isn't valid for this property." I presume that is because the field is not a memo data type, (apparently the only data type which supports RTF). It is in the format "*XXXX_XXXX*" where * and _ are literal characters and the X's represent numbers 0 through 9.

For context: The workflow of this DB is that it has a single form that when specifying an Id, queries a linked table, generates a report based on the query result, and outputs it to PDF.

The field's control source is a field from the query result.

Everything works fine but I need to be able to set this field to RTF. The font is a TrueType font if that makes any difference. Essentially I want to have a fixed height on the field and stretch it horizontally across the width. i.e. in CSS it would be defined roughly as "max-height: 30px; width: 100%;"

Things that I have tried:

In the Query Design View, setting the field's Text Format to Rich Text. I still receive an error when setting the field's Text Format in the Report Design View.

Other idea is to explicitly convert field to the Memo data type (anything over 255 implicitly gets converted to this type), but I am not sure of how to do that in SQl [MS SQL Server we would use something like CONVERT([fieldname], text)]

Would creating a custom format help? I'd imagine not because it would still be plaintext.

Thanks in advance for any help and comments.

Comment: MS Access 2007 preferred

Thanks again!

Comment: Also to note: in Word 2007 you would set the Font's Scale to 150%...again I'm pretty sure you can only do that on RTF, but just so you know the objective clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t change a BOUND text box to rich text unless the underlying column is a rich text column (memo). However, a simple workaround is place an un-bound text box on the report. Simply set the text to rich text in the property sheet (again, there is no need to use code to try and change this value). Once you have the text box placed on the form, then in the forms “detail-format” which fires for each record, you can in code go:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Me.MyTextBox = "<div><font face=Arial size=4 color=Blue>" & _
                   "<strong>My Blue Bold Text</strong></font></div>"

End Sub
```

So, you can pull values from other columns in the above code, but keep in mind for reports there must be a corresponding bound control to reference any column, where as a form does not have this requirement

Comment: This method also works in Access 2003 ADP when opened in A2007.  You can also do it without code - drop the field (eg custName) on the report and make it invisible, then copy/paste the field and change the control source to "=[custName]" - now set the format to "Rich Text".

Comment: Another point to note is that bound Rich Text controls work on forms - but not on reports.

Answer (score 2):

Just to address one of your suggested ideas:

> Other idea is to explicitly convert
>   field to the Memo data type (anything
>   over 255 implicitly gets converted to
>   this type), but I am not sure of how
>   to do that in SQl [MS SQL Server we
>   would use something like
>   CONVERT([fieldname], text)]

Sadly, the Access Database Engine does not support Standard SQL's `CAST()` function :(

Because the Access Database Engine shares an expression service with the VBA5 library (why not VBA6? -- who knows?!), it can use most of the VBA cast functions, however sadly the mapping between data types is not good. The only relevant function is `CStr()` (cast to `String`) but how its result are coerced to the various Access Database Engine text data types (variable length `VARCHAR`, fixed length `CHAR`, with or without Unicode compression, and `MEMO`) sadly is undocumented.

There is one exception: the Access Database Engine has its own `CDEC()` (cast to `DECIMAL`) function but sadly it has always been [completely broken](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225931/en-us).

Comment: how is cast() going to help a rich text formatting problem in a repot? (did you even bother to read the post????) -1 for this off topic...

Comment: Albert D. Kallal: I'm addressing the part of the question where the say, "Other idea is to explicitly convert field to the Memo data type... I am not sure of how to do that... in SQl [MS SQL Server we would use something like CONVERT([fieldname], text)]..." I've edited my answer to make its relevance to the question clearer to the casual observer ;)

Comment: There are MANY VBA conversion functions that you can use. CBool(), CByte(), CCur(), CDate(), CDbl(), Cstr() (the list goes on). 

We don’t lack casting in access at all (if anything, we have more options then sql server in this regards).

However, simply casting the column to memo is not sufficient since when you create a menu, you ALSO have to change the column setting in table design to rich text. So the rich text setting for a memo is optional. A simple casting to memo will not solve this problem. One also has to enable (set) the text setting for that memo column to rich text.

Comment: By way, I voted this back up, since the person did mention sql server in their question...so fair enough..

Comment: Cite please for the VB5 comment.

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal: the VBA cast functions were not designed for SQL, most notably do not support the NULL value. But let's not argue, thanks for the upvote, you are a gent :)

Comment: @David W. Fenton: citations for the Access Database Engine are hard to come by! The best I can do is the MSDN article that *seems* to enumerate the VBA functions that are supported by Jet 4.0. If you are familiar with the VBA6 library you will be able to note that none appear. The Replace() would be really nice to have. Article is 'How to configure Jet 4.0 to prevent unsafe functions from running in Access 2000 and Access 2002' (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239482).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this directly with a bound control unless it is defined as a Memo/Long Varchar field. If that is not the case, here is a workaround:

1. Make sure the bound control, e.g. BoundControlX, that has the rich text formatting is in the report. Leave the text format as plain. (Normally the bound control would also be set to not visible.)
2. Create an unbound control, e.g. UnboundControlY. Make it visible and set the text format to Rich Text.
3. Set the Control Source property of the unbound control to: =[BoundControlX]

For more details see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-delete-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630

Answer (score -3):

Try making the text field the last field in the table. I seem to recall somewhere that you can only have one memo field per table and that memo field must be the last field.